# Find a substring, that contains whitespaces (PHP)

Tags: php, string, find, substring, whitespace

I can't figure out this problem, could anyone help please.

How to find a substring in a string, if substring contains white spaces?

Example - I have a string stored in database that looks something like this:

```
$string = "Color: black; Weight: 2.3 kg; Screen size: 15.6''; Screen resolution: 1366 x 768;"
```

Is there a way to get the position of this substring?

```
$substring = "Screen size:";
```

What I'm trying to achieve in general is, I want to get the value after the semicolon, depending on the substring. For example:

if *substring = "Color:"* then return *black*

if *substring = "Weight:"* then return *2.3 kg*

and so fort.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @frz3993 does explode find a substring with white spaces? I forgot to mention, that there are also other information in my string. And it can contain following among others: "Screen size: 15.6''; Somethingelse size: 20m". So, that means I can't search just for *size:*, I need to find a specific word sequence

Comment: Or a `preg_match` is probably a viable solution too.

Comment: `explode()` doesn't find anything. It will just like break the string to array. Example, you will have an array like `['Color: black', 'Weight: 2.3 kg]`, which then you will `explode()` again delimited by `:`. Probably use `array_walk()` and `trim()` too.

Comment: @frz3993 you are right, sorry, I forgot that explode returns an array. Thank you!

Comment: I guess I'm late, as the answer was already accepted, but you may want to to take a look at my answer too, it may help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably get the work done like this. I tried to give you a step by step solution so you can understand it.
Don't hesitate looking into the PHP docs, if there are functions that you don't know.

Initial string

```
$string = "Color: black; Weight: 2.3 kg; Screen size: 15.6''; Screen resolution: 1366 x 768;";

$array = explode(';',$string);
```

Now, `$array` looks like :

```
[
    "Color: black",
    "Weight: 2.3 kg",
    "Screen size: 15.6''",
    "creen resolution: 1366 x 768"
]
```

Then loop through array and explode again

```
$finalArray = array();
$foreach ($elem in $array) {
     $keyValue = explode(':',$elem);
     $finalArray[$keyValue[0]] = $keyValue[1];
}
```

Now `$finalArray` looks like :

```
[
    "Color" => "black",
    "Weight" => "2.3 kg",
    "Screen size" => "15.6''",
    "creen resolution" => "1366 x 768"
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh yes, this looks like a very good solution for my situation. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<?php

$string = "Color: black; Weight: 2.3 kg; Screen size: 15.6''; Screen resolution: 1366 x 768;";
$specs = array();
preg_match_all('/(.*?):\s+(.*?); ?/i', $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++) {
    $specs[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
}

function whatIsThe($item, $specs){
return $specs[$item];
}

echo whatIsThe("Color", $specs);
//black
echo whatIsThe("Screen resolution", $specs);
//1366 x 768
//etc...
```

---

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/Lcy70C)

Comment: Thank you, sir! This looks like a very interesting solution and the resulting 'whatIsThe' function looks nice! I will try this aswell, as soon as I get some free time!